# getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist

Tags: plutus

Running `cabal update` within nixos in my app fails with the following:

```
$HOME/my-app/dist-newstyle/src/plutus-ap_-cbcc5c6ab544aad6/web-ghc: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same here. Trying to run cabal

Comment: I've been able to figure out the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is caused by the `cabal.project` file in [plutus-starter template](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter).

In the following section:

```
-- Plutus apps revision from 2022-04-06
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps.git
  tag: v0.1.0
  subdir:
    doc
    freer-extras
    playground-common
    plutus-chain-index
    plutus-chain-index-core
    plutus-contract
    plutus-example
    plutus-contract-certification
    plutus-ledger
    plutus-ledger-constraints
    plutus-pab
    plutus-pab-executables
    plutus-playground-server
    plutus-script-utils
    plutus-streaming
    plutus-tx-constraints
    plutus-use-cases
    web-ghc
```

An obsolete `plutus-apps` tag is still being used and it is expected that `web-ghc` folder is still present.

To fix the issue, I repaced the above `subdir` section with the following (found in the `packages` section in `cabal.project` file of the latest version of `plutus-apps`):

```
cardano-streaming
doc
freer-extras
marconi
marconi-mamba
playground-common
pab-blockfrost
plutus-chain-index
plutus-chain-index-core
plutus-contract
plutus-contract-certification
plutus-example
plutus-ledger
plutus-ledger-constraints
plutus-pab
plutus-pab-executables
plutus-script-utils
plutus-tx-constraints
plutus-use-cases
rewindable-index
```

And then replacing the `tag` with the latest tag found [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/tags)

Comment: I am getting the same but for `cardano-b_-c0de99f0ccd585cd/strict-containers`: `cardano-b_-c0de99f0ccd585cd/strict-containers: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist (No such file or directory)`. Do you know what I can do? Thanks

Comment: what `plutus-apps` tag are you using? there seem to be an obsolete reference to `strict-containers` in `cardano-binary`. Perhaps, the version of `cardano-binary` is what's obsolete. You might want to give it a look